# UIFont: Font size differs

Tags: ios, uifont

I am setting a custom font to all `subviews` (such as `UILabels`) inside my `view` by a custom function. However, if I try to correct the font size for specific `UILabels` only via

```
[lbl_EXAM_Statistics setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Regular" size:13]];
```

The 13point seems to be a little "too small" from what was given me from the Screendesign. 
In the psd file however its 13pt to be exact.

Why does the 13pt font size differ from the 13pt font size in my app?

In the screenshot the above text is from the psd file, the bottom one from the iphone simulator.

If I want to get near the text size from the Screendesign to my app I'd have to use somewhat of 18pt - but I cant waste time playing around how to get the exact pt, thats a huge timewaste with all the font size I have to specify directly. So there must be a better way.

[image]

Comment: It looks a LOT bigger in the top example. Also, you use “PSD” and “PDF” to describe this, are there two files?

Comment: Is 100% set in Simulator->Window->Scale ?

Comment: @ WilShipley No, theres no PDF file. Just a typo.
@ avuthless It was set to 75, I changed it to 100% - but still the font is too small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Totally depends on your psd.
Best is to set your metrics in Photoshop in pixels. So you can see the size of your font in pixels.

Then if your PSD is at retina size (640 px width), you just have to devide by 2 the px size of your font and you will have the good result on your app.

In the end, don't use pt but px in your PSD and it will be allright (just have to think that 1point in iOS is 2px on retina screen and 1px on non-retina)

Comment: The PSD File is at retina size (640 px width). I'll ask my graphics team to change the fonts from pt to px, if possible. (They'll hate me for that). Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: No no, your graphic team is not involved. You just need to set your photoshop (in settings of it) metrics in pixels (more convenient for a developer).
Then you will have the size of fonts in pixels. And you will just have to look at it, divide by 2 and set it to your `[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Regular" size:13]`

Comment: Gotcha. But it says its 27,78px and if I devide that by 2 to I come around the same 13.x which almost my output from before. Also the PSD file was set at 200dpi, I changed that to 72. Now I would have to multiple that 13.x by 2 to have the retina font size? Its my first attempt to apply a Screendesign to an app (also my first app), so sorry for the noob questions. :(

Comment: We all need to start from somewhere ;)
Dpi won't really change anything, since it's "point per pouce" it's only useful when you want to print something. All you need is you psd do 640px or 320px width. Then if your font says 27,78px, do `[UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Regular" size:27.78f/2]` and you will have the exact result of your psd in your app. (nothing force you to set integer for your font size).

Comment: Just realized that the app wont work < iOS 7 so all devices are considered to have a retine display. So the value 27.x pt coming from the psd file is already for retina displays. The retina simulator however cant handle the 27.x pt (its too big now).

Comment: You misunderstand... (but it's hard to explain with text). On iOS, you count distance in points. For example, your screen is 320 point large. On non-retina, 1point = 1pixel. On retina (because pixels are smaller) 1point = 2pixels. This way, if you define a `UIView` which is 320 width, it will do 320px on non retina, and 640px on retina (so it will take all the screen's width. It's the same with font size. If you set a font to size 13, it means it will be 13px height on non-retina and 26px height on retina display.

Comment: BUT point in photoshop are different from point in iOS, really nothing in common. Avoid them and use pixels in photoshop, nothing else.
So, if you read 27px for your font height in photoshop (be sure it's "px" not "pt" or whatever), and if your PSD is 640px width, then if you set 27.0f/2 as size on iOS **IT WILL be the same size** as your PSD. If you see them different, it's because your PSD is scaled larger or thiner than you app scale. But in noway it's a problem of code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45919/discussion-between-anc-ainu-and-pquerner)

Comment: Please describe why you think using pt in Photoshop is a bad idea.

Comment: Because if you use point without understanding what they are, you will  have this kind of problem again.
Points depends on the ppi/dpi of your psd. Pixels don't depend on any other calculation. So if you don't know why you use 72ppi or 144ppi you can get lost. But if you read in pixels, you are sure of the result (cause one pixel on a psd is one pixel on iOS, simpler).
1 point on PSD is 1 point on iOS only if you set the good ppi so it's less clear.

I always prefer count with something technical (pixels) than something which is based on screen real size in inches.

Comment: Like I said in chat Anc Ainu, your solution just works perfectly. I have somewhat around 37pt (from the "Prüfungs.." text) and if I convert that to px via Photoshop (changing metrics) it will say somewhat around 18px, which is just the value that is correct to use) But also your text now made it very clear what you meant. I did understand you and will focus on that in the future. Really appreciate it! Kudos!!

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop's font size and the iPhone's should match assuming the PSD file is set to 72dpi (or 144 for retina images).

You can check this in Photoshop using Image->Image Size... and then set the resolution to 72 pixels/inch (keeping the pixels untouched by unchecking "Resample Image:"). If the image is for retina resolution, use 144 pixels/inch.

This will not change the image in any way but make all pt measurements in Photoshop match the iPhone's coordinate system, retina or not.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. PPI was set to 200, I changed it to 72 ppi.